# What is the purpose of this MySQL database flag in Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am creating a MySQL instance in Cloud-SQL. I have enabled audit-logs for cloud SQL IAM ->Audit log:

[image]

When I configure the instance for MySQL 5.7 in Cloud-SQL console, I am noticing a flag **audit_log** beta:

[image]

If I set it to **ON** and create the MySQL instance in Cloud-SQL, I notice that this is not giving me any extra logs like **DML** statements in the Logging console. Even without setting this flag, I get the same logs in the Logging console.  What is the purpose of this flag?

Comment: 1) Did you enable Cloud SQL audit logs? 2) Which log are you looking at for the DML statements? 3) The DML statements should be in Data Access Audit Logs.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of that flag is described in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/audit-logging):

> Google Cloud services write audit logs to help you answer the questions, "Who did what, where, and when?" Your Cloud projects contain only the audit logs for resources that are directly within the project.
>
> Cloud Audit Logs provides the following audit logs for each Cloud project, folder, and organization:
>
> - Admin Activity audit logs
> - Data Access audit logs
> - System Event audit logs
> - Policy Denied audit logs

You can check more details for specifics on how this is handled for each type of database in Cloud SQL by following the link provided.

Comment: I'm afraid that that documentation is not for that flag. That documentation is for Cloud Audit Logs. I believe this flag is for the [MySQL Enterprise Audit plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/audit-log.html#:~:text=When%20installed%2C%20the%20audit%20plugin,databases%20and%20tables%20they%20access.), but I'm not sure